# How is render_views implemented in RSpec (is it a variable, method)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

Learning RSpec 3+, and learning that in order to render the template from the controller, you have to write `render_views` within a example group like so:

```
 describe CustomersController do
    describe "GET INDEX" do
      render_views
        it "renders the index template"
          expect(response.body).to match(/Customer List/)
        end
     end
  end
```

Just wondering how the implementation of it, more specifically, how does it work behind the scenes. Is render_view a method, a variable? Just wondering how RSpec knows to render the views for that particular example group, if `render_views` is typed in?

Answer (score 0):

You can see for yourself in the [rspec-rails source code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb).